# unhandled exception with access violation error

Tags: c++, access-violation

I am writing a console application using someone else's header file.

The .h has:

```
class DllItem SfAccess
{
public:

    SfAccess();
    ~SfAccess();


    std::string getVersion();

}
```

So in my .cpp I have added:

```
void main()
{
    SfAccess access;


    std::string version = access.getVersion();

}
```

This gives me the error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x5568A9E8 (msvcr120d.dll) in access.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00303022.
```

What does this actually mean? And what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Without seeing what `getVersion()` does it's impossible to tell.

Comment: We need to see the implementation of `getVersion()`

Comment: It's impossible to tell for sure without seeing `getVersion()`. However, an access violation means that `getVersion()` is using a bad pointer internally, trying to read memory to which it has no access.

Comment: Its locked inside a dll, so I cannot see. The docs that I have state that it returns a string...

Comment: Are you sure it returns a `std::string` and not a `char*` ?

Comment: the header has std::string getVersion(); I tried changing it to char*, but intelsense complains

Comment: Any other functions in that header? Perhaps an initialization function you need to call before the `SfAccess` becomes usable?

Comment: perhaps i should be using pointers? 

   SfAccess* access;


    std::string version = access->getVersion();

instead? This gives me an error:   'uninitialised local variable access used...